# Is it possible to add the value of a checkbox if checked into a text field?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, checkbox, parsley

Is it possible to add the value of a checkbox if checked into a text field?

I have this form...

http://xotio.com/photos/download/turk.html

I'm trying to add the value of a checkbox into a textbox if the checkbox has been clicked.

In my form there is one text box and three checkboxes per image (one of the checkboxes opens up more checkbox options and i'm not concerned about those color choices as much). I'm trying to add the 'value' of the three main checkboxes into the text field above.  Is that possible?

the values of the checkboxes i would like are the ' lost' and ' none' and ' blurry' options and add their values to the textbox above if they get checked.

In the end I'm trying to use parsley to validate each of the textboxes for data before it submits my form.  There are occasionally instances when no data is entered in the textbox, but the user has checked the right boxes and I want it to validate and can't come up with any ideas except this... any help or ideas would be great.  thanks in advance and sorry for the long winded complex question.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: that's great you know it's possible.  i've looked for several days now and can't figure it out. can't you point me in some kind of positive direction instead of simply saying yes.  obviously i'm looking for more than a yes or no answer

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example for your reference:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" value="lost" onclick="sendValueToTextBox(this)">lost
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="none" onclick="sendValueToTextBox(this)">none
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="blurry" onclick="sendValueToTextBox(this)">blurry
    <br>

    <input type="text" id="fg">


    <script language=javascript>
    function sendValueToTextBox(checkbox) {
    var textbox=document.getElementById("fg");
    if (checkbox.checked)
        textbox.value=checkbox.value;
    else
        textbox.value="";
    }
    </script>

 </body>
  </html>
```